# proof verification: problem 1.3.24 from Shreve and Karatzas ii

Tags: probability, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

> Assume that $\{X_{t}, \mathcal{F_{t}}, 0 \leq t < \infty\}$ is a right-continuous submartingale and $S \leq T$ are stopping times of $\mathcal{F_{t}}$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X_{T\wedge t}|\mathcal{F_{S}}] \geq X_{S \wedge t}$ a.s. P, for every t $\geq 0$.

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462262/problem-1-3-24-ii-karatzas-and-shreve-ex-t-wedge-t-mathscrf-s-ge-x-s). I have a different approach, but I'm not sure whether or not it works. In particular, I have not used the assumption that $X_{t}$ is right-continuous.

proof: From the optional stopping time theorem for bounded stopping times, $\mathbb{E}[X_{T\wedge t}|\mathcal{F_{S\wedge t}}] \geq X_{S \wedge t}$.

On $\{S \leq t\}$, $\mathbb{E}[X_{T\wedge t}|\mathcal{F_{S}}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{T\wedge t}|\mathcal{F_{S \wedge t}}]  \geq X_{S \wedge t}$.

On $\{S > t\}$, $T \geq S > t$, $\mathbb{E}[X_{T\wedge t}|\mathcal{F_{S \wedge n}}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{t}|\mathcal{F_{S \wedge n}}] = X_{t} \geq X_{S \wedge t}$, where we choose $n > t$. We can send $n \uparrow \infty$ and by Lévy's theorem, $\mathbb{E}[X_{T\wedge t}|\mathcal{F_{S \wedge n}}] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X_{T\wedge t}|\mathcal{F_{S}}]$. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[X_{T\wedge t}|\mathcal{F_{S}}] \geq X_{S \wedge t}$ as desired.

Comment: The optional stopping theorem in continuous time is generally stated (and proved) for right-continuous processes.  How do you avoid that hypothesis?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Aha, you are right! Thanks for the reminder. But is the rest of the proof correct??

Comment: I can't follow the "On $\{S>t\}$" part.